# Project Is not archieving in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm unable to archive my project, I have signed in already....

All I'm getting is this error:
No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.

[image: Project Info]

[image: Accounts screenshot]

Comment: Ok. do you have the paid developer certificate... if so then only you can create a archive to share the build with users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Purchase a paid developer account from apple to share your app with the customers.
2. Create your developer certificate in developer.apple.com site.
3. Create your app id and add your customer's UDIDs
4. create your application distribution profile.. which includes UDIDs of users
5. Then create the archive then share the app.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have Generic iOS Device selected or one of your iOS simulators?  I found that Archive was grayed out when I had a simulator selected.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a iOS Developer license?  Unlike your first screen shot (of your Xcode\Preferences\Accounts page) I have plenty of Provisioning Profiles.   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html

Comment: this question is detailed here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303524/make-an-ipa-for-iphone-and-ipad