# Make an .IPA for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

As I had asked this question already and didn't get the answer that I needed, the problem is as follows:

I developed a game for both iPhones and iPads. Everything is working fine but now I want to *Archive* my project. As I already have signed in for an Apple account, the problem is I don't  have another device to register with.

And, according to Apple's terms and condition **"Creating a provisioning profile requires one or more devices to be registered with your Account."**

Is there any way we can get it done without costing any money?

[image]

Comment: When you are creating de `provisioning profiles` is `developer.apple`, exist a step where is necessary add devices to the provisioning. Check that step

Comment: If you already have signed up for an Apple Dev Account and paid the $99 fee, you will not have to pay anything else. Creating provisioning profiles is basically just a formality. They want you to simply connect any iOS device to your Mac (maybe a friend's, if you don't have one, it really doesn't matter) and registering it with it's UDID. You create the profile; then, in Xcode, you download the profile and can continue archiving your binary and uploading it to iTunes Connect and the AppStore. Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: I have only signed in for an apple account didn't pay 99$ Apple developer account fee.. @LinusG.

Comment: Well then it's pretty obvious to me what you should do. Apple does not allow you to upload apps to the AppStore without paying the $99 dev fee.

Comment: is there any way i can create Provisioning profile without registering  another device with my account. @Suragch

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand you at first. So you want to create an archive without spending the money to buy a real device. Is that correct? Why do you want to create an archive if you don't have a device to run it on?

Comment: i want to make an .ipa and send it to another person @Suragch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that the purpose of the archive is to send the IPA to someone else. For that to work, the app needs to be provisioned for the device it's going to run on - that other person's device.

So, ask that person for their device UDID (that they can get from iTunes), then register it in your account in the apple developer portal member center and build using that.

It should be an ad-hoc configuration that you create.

Comment: that sounds good can you please tell me what is a uuid and how can i get it?

Comment: https://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid

Answer (score 2):

What XCode is complaining here is that you need to register the devices that you want the archive to run on! Or, it can be an expired license causing the trouble.

**Note:** Check in **Keychain** for any expired licenses. Go to View -> Show Expired Licenses. And, remove any or all of the expired licenses in System, Root, and any other categories. Mainly its the **WWDC License** causing the hassle.

Remove your iOS Development and Provisioning License(s).

Now, after removing all the licenses, add back your Provisioning profile, and the developer profile license. That should do it.

Start a clean build, and archive now. This should accept the archive. Do not forget to register a new device UDID in developer.apple.com portal. It is needed for TestFlight.

If you have any queries, please ask us in the comments.

Comment: Hey @Suman Adhikari first of all I'm not a Sir I'm a Junior to You  and second I don't have an Apple developer account as i mentioned earlier i only have an apple ID that's all.